# Salesforce Formula Text Value Based on Custom Field Picklist Value

Tags: formula-field

Basically, on Cases, I have:

Department(picklist values=Ecom, B2B, etc.) 

Manager(text field) 

Employee 1(text field) 

Employee 2(text field) 

Employee 3(text field) 

Employee 4(text field)

This is what I am trying to do in real time, not on save (workflow rule won't work because it only does field updates after creating the ticket, not during the creation of it):

`IF(ISPICKVAL(Department__c, "Ecom"),Employee_1__c="John Smith", Employee_2__c="Jane Doe", etc.)`

It keeps telling me I can't use a formula on the picklist field so then I tried to do it on each of the employee fields but they are not formula and only text fields.

I created another field that is Formula(text) and put in a formula:

`IF(ISPICKVAL(Department__c,"Ecom"),"test",null)`

This works but only for the formula(text) field, if I try to have it update the other text fields, it also does not allow me to do this and gives a boolean error, tried replacing null with "false" "true" with no difference.

Answer (score 1):

This is something that you cannot do with a formula field.

A formula field evaluates to a single value and can look at other fields to do this. It can't set any other field values other than it's own.

To do this, probably the easiest way would be a process (Open the the process builder and make a new process)

You could also do this with several workflows. Each workflow would have to evaluate branch of the logic.

The process would look something like this:

[image]

Comment: But doesn't the process only "fire" on "save"?

Comment: Oh I see... for this you need custom UI, because you are changing field values before save, which will require javascript. So this would require a custom visualforce page or a Lightning component. Not super easy. Actually, there might be a way - dependent picklists. Put your department as the source picklist and your other fields as dependent ones (they will have to become picklists). This way you can have realtime updating of the dependent values when you change the department.

Answer (score 0):

Hey you should try this:

we have CASE function in formula field.

```java
CASE( RSM_Sub_Region__c,
"1-North East", "NAME",
"2-Mid East", "NAME",
"3-South East", "NAME",
"None")
```